# Using includes with c++ shared libraries

Tags: c++, include, shared-libraries

I have a few functions that need to use math.h and time.h that I'd like to stick in a c++ shared library.

I'm having a hard time finding examples through google.

Where do I put the #include , the main file? The library cpp? or should it be in the make file? Is there any special syntax involved?

Answer (score -1):

If anything in `math.h` or `time.h` shows up in your library routines' interface, then the includes must be in your library's `.h` since they must be visible to the code that calls your library routines. Othewise it's quite acceptable (to the compiler, at least,) to hide them away inside the library's `.cpp` file.

Comment: I tried before I asked the question but can't get it to work. Right now I have the two includes right at the top of the Library's cpp file, before any of the functions. That's what you meant, right?

Comment: just the standard "this function is not defined" - it looks just like the errors you get when you forget to put the include you need in.

Comment: *Which* "function is not defined?" That would pretty much pinpoint the problem.